# Is "girdling root" *really* 环根 in Chinese?

Tags: translation, meaning

Baidu translates `girdling root` as 环根.

Icibia quotes Baidu with the exact same entry.

Baidu images returns nothing resembling a girdling root upon 环根 search.

Baidu also returns very little about 环根 itself, mostly giving results about 环根芹[属].

- Is "girdling root" *really* 环根 in Chinese?

Comment: In [*Tree Risk Assessment Form*](http://www.trees.gov.hk/filemanager/content/attachments/annex_b.pdf) provided by the HK government, `girdling root` is translated as `缠绕根`; in the thesis [*Research on The Girdling Roots of Three Street Trees in Taichung*](http://handle.ncl.edu.tw/11296/ndltd/08359120062927062121) by a Taiwanese student, it is translated as `环根`. And [dict.cnki.net](http://dict.cnki.net), which mainly reflects the translating convention in mainland China, replies `环生根` (though for this term it doesn't cite any paper so I cannot confirm it's actually used by mainland scholars).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be short, yes.

環根 is the roots growing around the tree trunk, with time, both the roots and the trunk would grow thicker, to the point when they pressure each other, causing the tree to grow weak and even wither. [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC4QFjACahUKEwjY1qWDytPIAhVBpIgKHbhUD-E&url=http%3A%2F%2Fla2.thu.edu.tw%2Fdownload.php%3Ffilename%3D17_3f153afa.pdf%26dir%3Dwriting_journal%2F8%26title%3D%25E9%259B%25BB%25E5%25AD%2590%25E6%25AA%2594%25E4%25B8%258B%25E8%25BC%2589&usg=AFQjCNErK9ivtssntUCK7MAqvJxKjuiHpw&sig2=gBlxJUknlccNF_Gb_XgpmQ&bvm=bv.105814755,d.cGU&cad=rjt) (PDF download) is a study done by Associate Professor Chang Chin Yu from Department of Landscape Architecture, Tunghai University. Sorry it's in traditional Chinese cause I'm from Taiwan (plus Tunghai University is in Taiwan). I believe Google translate can do the traditional-to-simplified work for you ;)